# Parse, MagicalRecord and CoreData save and update with async operation

Tags: ios, core-data, parse-platform

I'm facing the problem with `MagicalRecord` and `Parse`.

I have a model, that stores chat messages. When user adds a message it is persisted to storage, then uploaded to `Parse`, and then updated with parse objectId.

Here is my code:

```
// create message
__block ChatMessageModel *newMessage = nil;

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // depending on message type - create message with text or image
    // here is just [ChatMessageModel MR_createInContext:localContext] and setting values
    if (text) {
        newMessage = [ChatMessageModel createWithText:text andAuthor:author onDate:messageDate inChat:[self.chatModel MR_inContext:localContext] inContext:localContext];
    } else if(imageData) {
        newMessage = [ChatMessageModel createWithData:imageData andAuthor:author onDate:messageDate inChat:[self.chatModel MR_inContext:localContext] inContext:localContext];
    }        
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // if successfuly persisted
    if (success) {
        ChatMessageModel *savedMessage = [newMessage MR_inThreadContext];

        // upload data to Pasre. Here is just creating a PFObject, filling its fields and uploading to parse in background
        [self uploadToParseWithText:text orImageFilePath:savedMessage.imageAddress onDate:messageDate forMessage:savedMessage withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, PFObject *chatMessage) {
            // if parse saved data
            if (!error) {

                // update objectId in message from parse
                [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
                    [[savedMessage MR_inContext:localContext] setObjectId:chatMessage.objectId];
                }];
            } else {
                // handle errors
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Everything goes fine until message is sent very often (parse hasn't respond to previous one) which leads (through fetchresultcontroller) to displaying wrong values in UI.

Any ideas how to make this code better and update exact message, that should be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm too inexperienced to get into details here. I don't want to give away a wrong answer. I had a similar problem with con-concurrency. In my experience, you never know exactly when a networking task is completed unless you work with delegate methods. This is because the server response time changes from one request to the next depending on a variety of factors.
But what might help: You can write a delegate method that another object (e.g. a `UITableViewController`) executes only when a certain operation is finished. Ex - only update the values in the UI when the Parse operation is finished.